# Call Javascript to return string as div ID

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

All I need is simply to append a 'W' to the end of the div ID if the screen width is greater than the height or an 'H' if the height is greater.

I don't know if this is even possible but I need to change the ID of a div tag depending on the what the function returns. I thought using Javascript would do it since PHP does not have the ability to detect screen sizes.

I've shown my ideas that have failed. Most of my code may by incorrect syntax since I don't know js well...

```
<script>
    function myFN(idName) { 
        return (window.screen.width > window.screen.height) ? idName+"-w" : idName+"-h";
    }
</script>

<div class="className" id="myFN(idName);"></div>
```

or maybe

```
<script>
    function myFN() {
        return (window.screen.width > window.screen.height) ? "-w" : "-h";
    }
</script>

<div class="className" id="idName"+myFN(); ></div>
```

Comment: This has the smell of an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). HTML IDs don't work like that. What is it that you are ultimately trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: Just a suggestion - in most cases it would be better to add a class name to the already existing class name instead of changing the id.

Comment: CSS Media Queries...

Comment: There is a problem with your logic. ID's are not meant for that, you should add a class, and define styles (e.g. `.className.vertical` or `#idName.horizontal`)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately (or fortunately), you can't invoke a javascript function as part of an html tag declaration. I suggest you take a look at jQuery, which makes it very easy to select an element, and then change its id:

```
$('#idName').attr('id', 'newId');
```

Can't get much simpler than that.

Answer (score 2):

You can't simply call `myFN()` in the html markup...To accomplish this you will have to change the id after the page is loaded:

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById('idName');
myDiv.id = 'idName' + myFN();

function myFN() {
    return (window.screen.width > window.screen.height) ? '-w' : '-h';
}
```